# Keyboard is not hiding when click on second textField

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have two textFields. On click, the first one is showing a qwerty keyboard and the second one is showing picker.
My issue is when I'm clicking on my first textField, the keyboard is showing properly. Now, After I type anything, I directly want to click on the second textField which is the showing picker and the keyboard should disappear, but the keyboard is still there.
I want to hide the keyboard as soon as I click on the second textField.

Comment: first when second textfield is clicked do self.view.endEditing then present picker

Comment: i did...but not working

Comment: ..remove textfild & use button why use textfield

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to achieve this -

**First:** Use the UITextFieldDelegate.
For that- 
List the UITextFieldDelegate in your view Controller's protocol list like,

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Then make your ViewController conform to the Textfield's delegate to implement the methods like `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, and `textFieldDidEndEditing:`

So, go to the `viewDidLoad` method and conform to the UITextField's protocol like-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.firstTextField.delegate = self; //assuming your first textfield's 
                                         //name is firstTextField
   //Also give your first textfield a tag to identify later

    self.firstTextField.tag = 1;
}
```

Now, you are set to implement the delegate methods. But, to achieve your target first, you need to take a UITextField instance to know when you are typing in the firstTextField. So, declare a property of `UITextField` type. Do that in the interface file like-

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UITextField *currentTextField;
```

Now in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method, assign the firstTextField instance to the currentTextField when you start typing in it like-

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
       if(textField.tag == 1){
           self.currentTextField = textField;
       }
}
```

After that in the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method, check if it is the current textfield from which you are coming out and dismiss the keyboard like-

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
          if(textField.tag == 1){
              [self.currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
          }
          return YES;
     }
```

**Second**: You can use UIResponder. As ViewControllers inherit from UIResponder, you just override the method- `touchesBegan:withEvent` method, something like-

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
      [self.view endEditing:YES];// this will do the trick
}
```

In this case, when you click out side the textField, the keyboard should automatically disappear.

Comment: i'm doind same thing....but it's not working.

Comment: Which option did you take, the first or the second?

Comment: Post some code snippet if possible. Also post a screen shot of the storyboard with the connection inspector which is on the left side panel. Check yourself, if you have connected your textfields with its outlet in storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

use `UITextFieldDelegate` set delegate to `self` in `ViewDidLoad` and then put this code

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) 
{
    yourtextfieldname.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this way but its not working

Answer (score 2):

```
Step 1 :- Code for ViewController.h :-                                                   

//add UITextFieldDelegate just after UIViewController

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

Step 2 :- Code For ViewController.m :-

//inside viewdidLoad write following code, where txtInput is outlet for input text field

_txtInput.delegate = self;

// Last Thing write following code just above @end

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}

//that's it use this very simple way
```